# Automatic deletion of "thank you" comments

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comment-flags

We have this wonderful system whereby comments which say "thank you" or words to that effect can be flagged and automatically deleted. While this is in general a good way to keep the site clean, there is one situation where it causes a problem, which is where there are multiple answers to the question, none of which have been accepted, but one (or more) answer has a "thank you, it works" comment. If those "thank you" comments are deleted, there is no signpost to other users that those *specific* answers are a solution to the question (which accepting one of them would normally do).

I would like to request that flagged "thank you" comments not be automatically deleted from answers to a question where **no** answer has been accepted.

Comment: Wouldn't up-votes be an indicator for the usefulness of the question? Granted, it would only have a greater effect over a longer period of time, but since we are Q&A for future Q...

Comment: @Icepickle absolutely, but in tags like PHP a lot of questions are being asked by posters who don't have enough rep to up-vote and questions frequently have low double-digit views so there isn't much opportunity for answers to be upvoted. In my observation, generally the only questions and answers that see a lot of views/votes are those that have fairly trivial answers that a lot of users feel they could answer. So we do end up with a lot of questions that have an answer that works but no indication of that.

Comment: you've got 16 downvotes... and now we have a "thankyou" flag... I'm upvoting your question

Comment: @AlexAngelico ironic really... :)

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, accepting an answer is not mandatory on Stack Overflow and completely up to the OP. It therefore makes little sense to leave a "thank you" comment beneath an answer to indicate that the question was considered useful and "answered" by OP.

I'd say that indicating a question was answered by accepting it or posting a "thank you" comment is not very useful to begin with. We don't expect answers to be useful only to OP, and they might be the least qualified to judge which answer is the best. It just indicates that the answer helped *them* in some way. Upvotes are a better indicator of good answers, and I wouldn't mind if we got rid of the acceptance mark (and "thank you" comments) for good.